# how to extract data with end point method XHR with inspect element

Tags: web-scraping, socket.io, xmlhttprequest, endpoint

I am trying to print the odds of the main table of this webpage :

https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-aguilas-doradas-independiente-medellin-col-rid1164461.html

To do this, I use this url :
https://oddsv2.coteur.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NWnkYDw&sid=iHBGym6I1MzDqufVAPz-

It is from the XHR menu from network in inspect element.
Unfortunatly, when I pass the previous url in a browser, It gives me this output :

{"code":3,"message":"Bad request"}

My final goal will be to extract these data

Maybe you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this website has security checks to prevent scraping like you want to do.
Thus, it is impossible to call the internal API without being actually on the website.

If you have other questions, do not hesitate :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe you know what is the fastest method to extract the odds of the website without using internal API

Comment: Mmmh, do you know how to use Python?

Comment: Great, have you heard of the library BeautifulSoup? It allows you to scrape web data: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/.
With it, you can get the HTML code and then extract the informations you want pretty quickly.